# How can i embeded youtube video or local video in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile, browser, youtube

It works on PC browser, but when I test on my android device, Huawei u8860 android v 2.3. it doesn't work. I use `iframe` like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/0AUGkch3tzc?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

iframe works fine into jQuery mobile try to change your code to:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/0AUGkch3tzc?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```